# Hello, I request assistance with my code and i don't know what i did wrong c#

Tags: c#

i am new to c# and i followed a tutorial but it still says that there is some thing wrong with my code like " Assets/Scripts/Bounce.cs(46,41): error CS0104: 'Vector3' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector3' and 'System.Numerics.Vector3' "
another other things as well .
see code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;


public class Bounce : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float lerpTime;
    float currentLerpTime;
    float perc = 1;

    System.Numerics.Vector3 startPos;
    System.Numerics.Vector3 endPos; 
     
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("up") || Input.GetButtonDown("down") || Input.GetButtonDown("left") || Input.GetButtonDown("right") )
        {
             if(perc == 1)
            {
                lerpTime = 1;
                currentLerpTime = 0; 
            }

        }
        startPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("right") && gameObject.transform.position == endPos)
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("left") && gameObject.transform.position = endPos)
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("up") && gameObject.transform.position = endPos)
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z + 1);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("down") && gameObject.transform.position = endPos)
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z - 1);
        }
        currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime * 5.5F;
        perc = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos,endPos,perc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory? You use `Vector3` in multiple places. But the compiler doesn't know whether you mean `UnityEngine.Vector3` or `System.Numeric.Vector3` since you have both imports and both those classes exist there. You have to choose one everywhere.

Comment: 'Vector3' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector3' and 'System.Numerics.Vector3' means that Vector3 exists in the namepace UnityEngine and in System.Numerics. You need to choose which one of them you want. So if you want Unity then write UnityEngine.Vector3 instead

Comment: [How do i write a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is given since you have both:

```
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;
```

And a Vector3 type exist in both namespaces. So the compiler do not know witch one you want. Even worse, **you** do not seem like you know what type you want to use:

```
System.Numerics.Vector3 endPos;
```

and

```
gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos,endPos,perc);
```

are mutably incompatible, since you cannot mix the types without some conversion code. Such code is really easy to write, just add a extension method that takes one vector as input and creates the other, and use the full namespace when declaring your types, i.e.

```
        public static UnityEngine.Vector3 ToUnity(this System.Numerics.Vector3 v) =>
        new UnityEngine.Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
```

But in your case I would recommend removing the System.Numerics, and just stick to Unitys types. Things tend to be easier to manage when sticking to one type system, and there is no obvious reason that you need System.Numerics at all.